# sort in excel by word length (By point or pixel not by the number of characters)

Tags: excel, sorting, point

I need to sort the Excel column by word length

[image]

According to the form, all values have the same length (number of characters).
But they are not the same length on the screen (in terms of points or pixels or centimeters).
In the first case (number of characters), the len function solves the problem
How to implement the second mode?

Comment: write a function that generates the parameter you want, then sort on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sorting by text width**

Column `A` should be clear except the processed range (otherwise correct the macro to copy the selected range to the empty column then copy the sorted range back to its original location). Select the range (`A1:A4`) and run the next macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim av As Variant, i As Integer, v As Variant, c As Range
  ReDim av(Selection.Cells.Count + 1)
  For i = 1 To Selection.Cells.Count
    av(i) = Selection.Cells(i)
  Next
  Selection.Cells.ClearContents
  For i = 1 To Selection.Cells.Count
    With Selection.Cells(i)
      .Value = av(i)
      .EntireColumn.AutoFit
      .Offset(0, 1) = .EntireColumn.Width
      .ClearContents
    End With
  Next
  For i = 1 To Selection.Cells.Count
    Selection.Cells(i) = av(i)
  Next
  Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Set c = Range(Selection.Cells(1), Selection.Cells(1).Offset(Selection.Rows.Count - 1, 1))
  c.Sort c.Columns(2), xlDescending
  c.Columns(2).ClearContents
End Sub
```